# ImportError run python project from Google Drive in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, python-import, google-colaboratory

I mouth my Google Drive with Google Colab (follow the post by https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d)

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}

!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Then I place [Tensorflow nmt](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt) into drive/colab/ (drive is google drive root directory.

I run the command in Colab Cell

```
!python  drive/colab/nmt/nmt.py\
    --attention=scaled_luong \
    --src=src --tgt=tgt \
    --vocab_prefix=drive/colab/data/vi-vi/vocab  \
    --train_prefix=drive/colab/data/vi-vi/small_train \
    --dev_prefix=drive/colab/data/vi-vi/val  \
    --test_prefix=drive/colab/data/vi-vi/test \
    --out_dir=drive/colab/data/vi-vi/nmt_attention_model \
    --num_train_steps=12000 \
    --steps_per_stats=100 \
    --num_layers=2 \
    --num_units=128 \
    --dropout=0.2 \
    --metrics=bleu
```

With error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive/colab/nmt/nmt.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import inference
ImportError: cannot import name 'inference'
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are using relative import in `nmt.py` and your current directory is not the same as where `nmt.py` is located. And because of that python is not able to find the files. You can fix it by changing your directory to mnt using

```
%cd drive/colab/nmt/
```

and then running your command.